# Pylint Error: Unblanaced tuple unpackaing

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python by following book Named "learn python3 by hard way"

They gave this example of code.

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

But in VS code pylint giving me this error.

```
Possible unbalanced tuple unpacking with sequence: left side has 4 label(s), right side has 0 value(s)
```

Book writer hadn't explained this and I want to know what does this error means
But they also said

> Run the program like this (and you must pass three command line
> arguments):
> `$ python3.6 ex13.py first 2nd 3rd`

And how often python programmers use this method in practical world and any example of use-case.

Comment: That is because, initially there is no default value set for `argv`, so the Pylint shows that error.

Comment: That's a bad code example because it's not very tolerant of a different number of arguments and doesn't give useful feedback. In general LPTHW is not recommended: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints.

Answer (score 0):

The argument may not exactly be four. If it is less or more than 4, it may raise `ValueError`